# How to call MapActivity.java from MainActivity.java on click of button

Tags: android, google-maps

On executing this "Locate" button, I want my map to get input value from btnShowLoc function in MainActivity.java and display the same.

activity_main.xml

```
        <Button
        android:onClick="btnShowLoc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Locate" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        tools:context=".MapLocationActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public void btnShowLoc(View view) {
        EditText txtLat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLat);
        EditText txtLong = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLong);

//Need instruction about how to call MapActivity.java
    }


MapActivity.java

public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MapFragment map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        map.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng Device = new LatLng(28.7041, 77.1025);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Device).title("Device Location"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Device));
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        mMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`Intent`** to start your **`MapActivity`**

> An **[Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)** is an abstract description of an operation to be performed. It can be used with startActivity to launch an Activity, broadcastIntent to send it to any interested BroadcastReceiver components, and startService(Intent) or bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int) to communicate with a background Service.

Try this First send your **latitude** and **latitude** using Intent to **`MapActivity`** like below code

```
Intent i = new Intent(HotelDetailsClass.this, MapActivity.class);
i.putExtra("latitude","28.7041")
i.putExtra("longitude","77.1025");
startActivity(i);
```

now ad this code in your **MapActivity**

```
Double latitude, longitude;
Intent i = getIntent();
latitude = Double.valueOf(i.getStringExtra("latitude"));
longitude = Double.valueOf(i.getStringExtra("longitude"));
```

now load in map

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        // Add a marker in Location and move the camera
        LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(title));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 14.0f));


    }
```

Comment: my app is getting crashed on calling MapActivity.java

Comment: @SrijanChaudhary share your crash log what error you get

Comment: Post exception log

Comment: @SrijanChaudhary happy to help you